# Chrome browser close event issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In our web application, we need to execute a functionality when the user closes the browser using close(X) icon. We were using 'onbeforeunload'(with out event.returnValue) function to track the close event and execute our required function. It is not working when the user closes the browser after 1 minute.

The same behaviour is working fine in Firefox and Safari browsers. How to recognize the browser close event in Chrome browser?

Need to recognize window close event in Chrome browser

Comment: Can you provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?